# While I am using Lambda Initialization and validation I am getting error in amazon lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am facing this error for several days, and I don’t know how to solve, it anyone can help me, please?

basically, I am creating a chatbot on amazon lex V1, I have two intents Greeting and course. inside Greeting I am asking the user to enter their name and if the user is a student or professor. and I am checking in the lambda function if the user is a student bot will say "I can help you with your modules and assignments!"

when I tick the lambda initialization and validation the bot gives this error **An error has occurred: The server encountered an error processing the Lambda response** at the beginning when the user says "Hi".

when I tick the lambda at the fulfillment it works!

here is my code and a screenshot of the logs

````
const dispatch = require ('./dispatch');

module.exports.main = function(event, context, callback){
 
  try{
    console.log(`event.bot.name=${event.bot.name}`);
   dispatch(event, (response)=> callback(null, response));
    
  
    
  }catch (err){
    callback(err);
}
};
******************
const greeting = require('./greeting');

module.exports = function(intentRequest, callback){
    console.log(`dispatch userId=${intentRequest.userId}, intentName=${intentRequest.currentIntent.name}`);
    
    const intentName = intentRequest.currentIntent.name;
    console.log(intentName);
    
    if(intentName == "Greeting"){
        console.log(intentName + 'was called');
        return greeting(intentRequest, callback);
    }else{
        throw new Error (`intent with name ${intentName} not supported`)
};
    
};
********************
const lexResponses = require ('./lexResponse');
const lexResponse = require('./lexResponse');

module.exports = function(intentRequest, callback){
  
     const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;
     const source = intentRequest.invocationSource;
     const intentName = intentRequest.currentIntent.name;
     var userName = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots.user_name;
     var std_name = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots.std_name;
     
     console.log(userName);
     console.log(std_name);
     console.log(source);
     
    if(source === 'DialogCodeHook'){
    
          if(std_name == 'student'){
             console.log("it is here");
            const message ="I can help you with "
             
            callback(lexResponse.elecitSlot(intentRequest.sessionAttributes,intentName, slots, message));
            return;
        }
    }
   
};

Response Method

module.exports.elecitSlot =function (sessionAttributes, intentName, slots, slotToElicit, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'ElicitSlot',
            intentName,
            slots,
            slotToElicit,
            message
        },
    };
}
************```


when I tick initialization and validation log:

**2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO event.bot.name=Chatbot

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO dispatch userId=mmtqxwob0lfzu35u39damzctl7pmfngq, intentName=Greeting

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO Greeting

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO Greetingwas called

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO null

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO null

2022-07-04T08:13:22.436+01:00   2022-07-04T07:13:22.436Z 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8 INFO DialogCodeHook

2022-07-04T08:13:22.444+01:00   END RequestId: 0c03eb78-35e9-4fd8-9a72-cabca7d915f8*
````

Comment: Can you share the logs from the validation phase when it breaks? I assume you're either looking for a value that does not exist and causing the lambda to break; without the correct error handling or the response format is incorrect for the validation step.

Comment: Dear, I have shared the logs from the validation, I will add the response method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code shared, it would appear that you are not providing Lex with a valid response for all scenarios.

```
   if(source === 'DialogCodeHook'){
          if(std_name == 'student'){
             console.log("it is here");
            const message ="I can help you with ";
            callback(lexResponse.elecitSlot(
                intentRequest.sessionAttributes,intentName, slots, message));
            return;
        }
    }
```

You need to tell Lex what to do when the value for `std_name` is not equal to `student`. In this scenario you can either direct Lex on where to go or let Lex decide for itself by returning a `delegate` response.

So, your code snippet should look something like the below:

```
   if(source === 'DialogCodeHook'){
          if(std_name == 'student'){
             console.log("it is here");
            const message ="I can help you with ";
            callback(lexResponse.elecitSlot(
                intentRequest.sessionAttributes,intentName, slots, message));
            return;
        }
    } else {
            callback(lexResponse.delegate(
                intentRequest.sessionAttributes, slots));
    }
```

The `delegate` method would be added to your response method file and would look something like below:

```
module.exports.delegate=function (sessionAttributes, slots) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Delegate',
            slots
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you it works, But is there any way to send a message with a delegate, for example, if the user is not a student show this message to the user " I can only answer student questions"?

Comment: If it works, kindly vote the answer up.
You cannot send a message with delegate as you're telling Lex to make a decision.
However, if `std_name` is not equal to `student` you can return a `close` response which will tell Lex to close the interaction. You can send your desired response message in the close.

Comment: will try with "close", to see what I will get. thank you for your help